# Can I run freepto or tails or Subgraph OS on rasberry pi?

Tags: operating-systems, privacy, raspberry-pi

I am new to the pi, do you guys think I can I run freepto or tails or Subgraph OS on the pi?

Since some of them are linux based I thought I would give it a try, but dunno.

Thx in advance for your response

Answer (score 2):

Tails and Subgraph OS state on their website that they only support x86 processors (and not ARM).

I could not find any similar information about freepto.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to do? Answer is: **no** from the box, but **yes** from the sources. But it is a bit **laborious** - so if you'll tell us more specifics of your task, I'll be able to help you further.